# How can I get line feeds in Ruby when writing out to a file:

Tags: ruby, file

My input file is:

```
1  
3  
5  
7  
9
```

I want my output file to be squares, one per line:

```
1  
9  
25  
49  
81
```

But I am getting:

```
19254981
```

i.e. no linespaces

My code is:

```
a= File.open('inputs')
b= File.open('outputs', 'w')
a.each_line do |one_num|
  one_number = one_num.to_i
  square= one_number * one_number
  b << square
end
```

Answer (score 2):

use `puts` instead of `<<`.

```
 b.puts square
```

**Side note:** you can do the whole thing as one long method chain:

```
File.open('outputs','w').puts(File.open('inputs').readlines.map{ |l| n=l.to_i; n*n })
```

Or somewhat more readably as nested blocks:

```
File.open('outputs','w') do |out|
  File.open('inputs') do |in|
    out.puts( in.readlines.map { |l| n=l.to_i; n*n } )
  end
end
```

Both of those solutions have the advantage of not leaving any dangling file handles despite the lack of explicit `close` statements.

Comment: `(l.to_i)**2` will save you another statement.